Computing the pushforward of a vector field
Example 8.20 of Lee's "Smooth Manifolds" is as follows:
Let $M$ and $N$ be the following open submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^2:$
$$\begin{align*}M &= \{(x,y) : y > 0 \text{ and } x + y > 0\}, \\ N&= \{(u,v) : u > 0 \text{ and } v > 0\},\end{align*}$$ and define $F: M \to N$ by $(x+y, x/y+1).$ We wish to compute the pushforward $F_*X,$ where $$X_{(x,y)} = y^2\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)}.$$
We can easily compute that $dF_{F^{-1}(u,v)}$ is represented by $$DF = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{v}{u} & \frac{v - v^2}{u}\end{pmatrix}$$and that $$X_{F^{-1}(u,v)} = \frac{u^2}{v^2}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{F^{-1}(u,v)}.$$ Lee then writes the following: applying (8.7) with $p=(u,v)$ yields the formula for $F_*X$: $$(F_*X)_{(u,v)} = \frac{u^2}{v^2}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right|_{(u,v)} + \frac{u}{v}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right|_{(u,v)}. \tag{$*$}$$ Where (8.7) is $$(F_*X)_q = dF_{F^{-1}(q)}(X_{F^{-1}(q)}).$$
I do not understand how to get $(*).$

This equation:
$$
DF = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
v/u & \frac{v-v^2}{u}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the representation of the linear operator $dF_{F^{-1}(u,v)}$ with respect to the basis $\lbrace \partial_x, \partial_y \rbrace$ in $M$, where $\partial_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, and $\lbrace \partial_u, \partial_v \rbrace$ in $N$, so all you have to do is to write $X$ as the vector column
$$
X_{(x,y)} = y^2 \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)} \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
y^2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
in the basis $\lbrace \partial_x, \partial_y \rbrace$ and do the matrix multiplication:
$$
(F_* X)_{(u,v)} \leftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
v/u & \frac{v-v^2}{u}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 \\
\frac{v}{u} y^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
to obtain $F_* X$ in the final basis $\lbrace \partial_u, \partial_v \rbrace$. Now by inverting $F$ we find $y = u/v$ so
$$
(F_* X)_{(u,v)} \leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
u^2/v^2 \\
u/v
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or using basis vectors:
$$
(F_* X)_{(u,v)} = \frac{u^2}{v^2} \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right|_{(u,v)} + \frac{u}{v} \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\right|_{(u,v)}.
$$
